# How to calculate confidence interval for dice hits?

Tags: probability-theory, dice, standard-deviation, variance, confidence-interval

There is a dice with $e$ edges $\left[1;e\right]$. The dice rolls in a one experiment $r$ times. Thus the edge numbered $1$ can be generated in this experiment from $0$ to $r$ times. I need to calculate theoretical 95% confidence interval for this count.

Here is my solution but I get wrong result.
For example if $edges=3$, $rolls=1000$, I get $\left[332;334\right]$.
What did I do wrong?

---

$E\left(e,1\right) = \frac{1}{e}$

$Var(e,1) = \left[\frac{1}{r} \cdot \left(\left(1 - E\left(e,1\right)\right)^2\right)\right] + \left[\frac{\left(r-1\right)}{r} \cdot \left(\left(0 - E\left(e,1\right)\right)^2\right)\right]$

$Var(e,r) = r \cdot Var(e,1)$

$\sigma\left(e,r\right)=\sqrt{Var\left(e,r\right)}$

---

$a\left(e,r,h\right) = 1.96 \cdot \frac{\sigma\left(e,h\right)}{\sqrt{r}}$

$b\left(e,r,h\right) = 1.96 \cdot \frac{\sigma\left(e,h\right)}{\sqrt{r}}$

---

$e: \text{edges}$
$r: \text{rolls}$
$h: \text{hits}$

Comment: Can you define what a 'hit' is?  Also, why should you assume the hits are normally distributed?

Comment: Hit is event, when the showed edge number of rolled dice is 1. I assume that count of hits after N rolls is normally distributed. (updated).

Comment: Is [332;334] actually a 5% confidence interval?

Comment: Maybe. I got 8.01% outcomes within this interval for 1'000'000 experiments. How can I correct my formulas?

Comment: You've posted this question twice - the other one is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1995942/16397).

Comment: Now the other one is deleted.

Comment: You're asking for a "confidence" interval for a random variable (the count), but this is usually called a *prediction interval". (Confidence intervals ordinarily pertain to fixed parameters of a distribution, such as the mean etc.)

Comment: (1) Your formula for the interval endpoints shows a standard deviation divided by the squareroot of the number of rolls, which would be appropriate if we were interested in estimating or predicting a mean value or proportion (i.e. a sum divided by the number of terms in the sum); however, here we're interested in the *sum* itself (i.e. the count), not divided by the number of rolls, so this denominator should be absent. (2)  Your formula for "$Var(e,1)$" should not depend on the number of rolls, but should be the variance of each Bernoulli random variable $X_i$ (i.e. $p(1-p)$) (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want what is called a *prediction interval* (PI, not "confidence interval") for $N_r$, where the random variable $N_r$ is the total number of rolls that produce a $1$ (out of $r$ rolls). Now $N_r= X_1+...+X_r$, where 
$$X_i = 
\begin{cases} 
1,  & \text{ if the ith roll is a } 1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and we have the normal approximation when $r$ is sufficiently large:

$$N_r = \text{Binomial}(r,p) \approx \text{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

where $$\\ \mu = E[N_r]=rp\\ \sigma^2= V[N_r]=rp(1-p)\\ p=P[X_i=1]=1/e$$ ($e$ being the number of sides on the die, which is assumed to be "fair").

NB: 
$$\begin{align}E[X_i] &= P[X_i=1]\ 1 + P[X_i=0]\ 0\\
&= p\ 1 + (1-p)\ 0\\
&= p\\
\\
V[X_i] &= P[X_i=1](1-E[X_i])^2 + P[X_i=0](0-E[X_i])^2\\
&= p(1-p)^2 + (1-p)(0-p)^2\\
&= p(1-p)\\
\\
E[N_r] &= E[X_1+...+X_r]\\
&= r\ E[X_1]\\
&= r\ p\\
\\
V[N_r]&=V[X_1+...+X_r]\\
&= V[X_1]+...+V[X_r]\quad\text{because these are independent}\\
&= r\ V[X_1]\\
&= r\ p(1-p)\\
\end{align}
$$

[An approximate $95\%$ PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval#Known_mean.2C_known_variance) for $N_r$ is then
$$\mu\ \pm\ 1.96\sigma, 
$$
because
$$P[\mu - 1.96\sigma < N_r < \mu + 1.96\sigma] \approx 0.95.
$$
For your example, $e=3,\ r = 1000:\ \  \mu\ \pm\ 1.96\sigma = 333.3\ \pm\ 29.2 \approx [304,363]$.